# Solidity - API calls of AccuWeather on Chainlink do not function as expected

Tags: api, solidity, chainlink

I am at the very beginning and am trying to understand how API calls exactly work. For this reason I am trying to deploy and make calls with the code posted by AccuWeather on chainlink market.

The code:

https://market.link/nodes/AccuWeather/integrations#CurrentConditionsResult

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract AccuweatherConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
    /* ========== CONSUMER STATE VARIABLES ========== */
    struct RequestParams {
        uint256 locationKey;
        string endpoint;
        string lat;
        string lon;
        string units;
    }
    struct LocationResult {
        uint256 locationKey;
        string name;
        bytes2 countryCode;
    }

    // Maps
    mapping(bytes32 => LocationResult) public requestIdLocationResult;
    mapping(bytes32 => RequestParams) public requestIdRequestParams;
    /* ========== CONSTRUCTOR ========== */
    /**
     * @param _link the LINK token address.
     * @param _oracle the Operator.sol contract address.
     */
    constructor(address _link, address _oracle) {
        setChainlinkToken(_link);
        setChainlinkOracle(_oracle);
    }
    /* ========== CONSUMER REQUEST FUNCTIONS ========== */
    /**
     * @notice Returns the location information for the given coordinates.
     * @param _specId the jobID.
     * @param _payment the LINK amount in Juels (i.e. 10^18 aka 1 LINK).
     * @param _lat the latitude (WGS84 standard, from -90 to 90).
     * @param _lon the longitude (WGS84 standard, from -180 to 180).
     */
    function requestLocation(
        bytes32 _specId,
        uint256 _payment,
        string calldata _lat,
        string calldata _lon
    ) public {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(_specId, address(this), this.fulfillLocation.selector);
        req.add("endpoint", "location"); // NB: not required if it has been hardcoded in the job spec
        req.add("lat", _lat);
        req.add("lon", _lon);
        bytes32 requestId = sendChainlinkRequest(req, _payment);
        // Below this line is just an example of usage
        storeRequestParams(requestId, 0, "location", _lat, _lon, "");
    }

    /* ========== CONSUMER FULFILL FUNCTIONS ========== */
    /**
     * @notice Consumes the data returned by the node job on a particular request.
     * @dev Only when `_locationFound` is true, both `_locationFound` will contain meaningful data (as bytes). This
     * function body is just an example of usage.
     * @param _requestId the request ID for fulfillment.
     * @param _locationFound true if a location was found for the given coordinates, otherwise false.
     * @param _locationResult the location information (encoded as LocationResult).
     */
    function fulfillLocation(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        bool _locationFound,
        bytes memory _locationResult
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        if (_locationFound) {
            storeLocationResult(_requestId, _locationResult);
        }
    }

    /* ========== PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ========== */
    function storeRequestParams(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _locationKey,
        string memory _endpoint,
        string memory _lat,
        string memory _lon,
        string memory _units
    ) private {
        RequestParams memory requestParams;
        requestParams.locationKey = _locationKey;
        requestParams.endpoint = _endpoint;
        requestParams.lat = _lat;
        requestParams.lon = _lon;
        requestParams.units = _units;
        requestIdRequestParams[_requestId] = requestParams;
    }
    function storeLocationResult(bytes32 _requestId, bytes memory _locationResult) private {
        LocationResult memory result = abi.decode(_locationResult, (LocationResult));
        requestIdLocationResult[_requestId] = result;
    }
}
```

I have deployed the contract, fueled it with LINKs. I can do the calls for the Location by entering the JobID, lat and long I found an AccuWeather (lat: 30.918 and long:-99.786) as well as the link payment. The call seems to be successful but when I take the requestID and use it to see the LocationResult I receive empty values.

I dont really know why it does not work or weather I forget to do something in between.

If I understand it correctly I need the LocationResult function to get information required for the fulfill function, is that correct?

I just hope someone faced the same problem and can help me. I would be very thankful for any suggestion!!

Comment: Can you check the address of operator.sol in the etherscan to see if there is any problem when the operator trying to write the info into your contract?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, I have not found anything suspicious, it seems to work...

Comment: Can you share the transaction sent by operator? which network you are using?